# XSLT: xsl:sort produces undesired newlines

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The task seems simple enough: Sort (locally) all elements in the input document by value of the attribute 'id'; otherwise the contents should be left unchanged.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
  <Group>
    <Item id="c"/>
    <Item id="a"/>
    <Item id="b"/>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Item id="f"/>
    <Item id="d"/>
  </Group>
</A>
```

**Desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
  <Group>
    <Item id="a"/>
    <Item id="b"/>
    <Item id="c"/>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Item id="d"/>
    <Item id="f"/>
  </Group>
</A>
```

Note that the sorting is local to each Group item. Which should make this very simple:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Modified identity -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Actual output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
    <Group>



        <Item id="a"/>
        <Item id="b"/>
        <Item id="c"/>
    </Group>
    <Group>


        <Item id="d"/>
        <Item id="f"/>
    </Group>
</A>
```

The problem is the undesired newlines. I obtain this result with Saxon6.5.5, Saxon-PE 9.4.0.4, Saxon-HE 9.4.0.4, Saxon-EE 9.4.0.4. Xalan introduces the same newlines plus additional fouling up of the formatting.

I've been staring myself blind at this, so I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as a top-level element. In this case, `*` is a wildcard that denotes all elements. Instead you could list specific elements you'd like to strip of their whitespace.

**Stlysheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Modified identity -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
   <Group>
      <Item id="a"/>
      <Item id="b"/>
      <Item id="c"/>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Item id="d"/>
      <Item id="f"/>
   </Group>
</A>
```